# Updating column values from one table to another

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables

```
X [id,event_time]
Y [x_id,z_id] -- here x_id is id from X and z_id is id from Z
Z [id,event_time]
```

Now I want to update the values of X[event_time] with Z[event_time]. Is there any query that can be formed for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update x
set x.event_time = t.event_time
from (
    select z.event_time
        ,y.x_id
    from z
    join y on z.id = y.z_id
    ) t
where x.id = t.x_id
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
UPDATE X
SET event_time = z.event_time
FROM Z z
JOIN Y y ON y.z_id = z.id
JOIN X x ON y.x_id = x.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE X
SET event_id = (SELECT z.event_id FROM Z INNER JOIN Y WHERE Z.id=Y.z_id and Y.x_id=X.id)
```